# Ошибка LNK2019 VS2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015, шаблоны-с++

Ошибка

> LNK2019   ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall
>   MassClass::~MassClass(void)" (??1?$MassClass@H@@QAE@XZ) в
>   функции _main DinamMass   D:\C++\Source.obj   1

Пробовал добавлять все файлы по отдельности, компилировал по отдельности, танцевал с бубном, но ни чего не помогло.

MassClass.h

```
#pragma once

template <typename T>
class MassClass
{
private:
    int size;
    T *ptr;
    void boundaries(int n,MassClass &m);
    void initsial(MassClass &m);
public:
    MassClass(int n = 0);
    void copy(MassClass &m1, MassClass &m2);
    void addrozmir(MassClass &m1, int n);
    void print(void);
    ~MassClass();
};
```

MassClass.cpp

```
#include "MassClass.h"
#include "math.h"

template <typename T>
MassClass<T>::MassClass(int n)
{
    if (n > 0)
        size = n;
        ptr = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = 0;
        }
    else
    {
        size = abs(n);
        ptr = new T[size];
        for (int i = 0; i < size i++)
        {
            ptr[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

template <typename T>
MassClass<T>::~MassClass()
{
    delegate[] ptr;
}

template <typename T>
void MassClass<T>::copy(MassClass &m1, MassClass &m2)
{
    delegate[] m1.ptr;
    m1.size = m2.size;
    m1.ptr = new T[m1.size];
    for (int i = 0, i < m2.size, i++)
    {
        m1.ptr[i] = m2.ptr[i];
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MassClass<T>::boundaries(int n, MassClass<T> &m1)
{
    if (m1.size < n)
    {
        std::cout << "Vihod za granitsi";
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MassClass<T>::addrozmir(MassClass<T> &m1, int n)
{
    delete[] m1.ptr;
    m1.ptr = new T[n];
    initsial(m1);
}

template <typename T>
void MassClass<T>::initsial(MassClass<T> &m1)
{
    for (int i = 0, i < m1.size, int i++)
    {
        m1.ptr[i] = 0;
    }
}

template <typename T>
void MassClass<T>::print(void)
{
    for (int i = 0, i < size, i++)
    {
        cout << i << " " << ptr[i];
    }
}
```

Source.cpp

```
#include <iostream>
#include <conio.h>
#include "math.h"
#include "MassClass.h"

using namespace std;

void main(void)
{
    MassClass<int> m1(10);
    m1.print();
    _getch();   
}
```

Ошибки

```
Серьезность Код Описание    Проект  Файл    Строка  Состояние подавления
Ошибка  LNK1120 неразрешенных внешних элементов: 3  DinamMass   D:\С++\Mass\DinamMass\Debug\DinamMass.exe   1   
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: void __thiscall MassClass<int>::print(void)" (?print@?$MassClass@H@@QAEXXZ) в функции _main DinamMass   D:\С++\Source.obj   1   
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall MassClass<int>::MassClass<int>(int)" (??0?$MassClass@H@@QAE@H@Z) в функции _main DinamMass   D:\С++\Source.obj   1   
Ошибка  LNK2019 ссылка на неразрешенный внешний символ "public: __thiscall MassClass<int>::~MassClass<int>(void)" (??1?$MassClass@H@@QAE@XZ) в функции _main    DinamMass   D:\С++\Mass\Source.obj  1
```

Comment: Так вынесите шаблоны методов в `.h`, компилировать их в `.cpp` не имеет смысла по определению. P.S. [Ну и вот...](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/search?q=LNK2019+template).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Определения шаблонных функций должны быть в заголовочных файлах. Смотрите, при компиляции `MassClass.cpp` *откуда компилятору знать*, что вы будете инстанцировать класс с типом `int`? Он этого не знает, и, соответственно, ничего не делает. А при компиляции `Source.cpp` он знает, но не может ничего инстанцировать - так как кода у него нет.

Вот и все...

P.S. Кстати, у вас куча ошибок в `MassClass.cpp`, но так как компилятор ничего не инстанцирует - он их просто не замечает...

Comment: Та я все уже по исправлял. Спасибо.